# Should those with question bans be allowed to edit their previous questions?

Tags: discussion

Should those banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow be allowed to edit their previous questions?

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070910/typeinitializationexception-when-using-suanshu-library-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Of course they should. Editing to make the questions better is the primary way *out* of the ban.

However, changing the whole question to something new, which that user appeared to, is not allowed. I rolled the edit back.

Comment: Good point.  I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 26):

Yes, they often *need* to edit their previous questions in order to improve them. Naturally, they shouldn't be completely changing a question that's already been answered. That will probably just get them deeper down in the hole they've dug.